# Distinguish between timeout or lost connection on serial port

Tags: go, serial-port, connection, timeout

Is there a way to distinguish between a lost connection and an expected timeout on reading from a serial port (/dev/tty... file descriptor) in golang 1.16 on a linux host?

All I get from two different implementations of "serial" for go are a error string holding only "EOF" in both scenarios. I tried os.IsTimeout() but there is no type associated with that error from io.file.

I need to know if I lost connection so I can reconnect (close and reopen the port). Without it is reconnecting on every timeout.

Can someone hint me to a way to distinguish these to scenarios or a different approach for handling a disconnected device?

Comment: How are you setting a timeout?

Comment: If you're using a termios based approach, then there isn't really any concept of a "disconnect", you can only detect if there is any activity. If the serial port is something like a usb adapter, then the kernel usually will unload the device and the `/dev/tty` descriptor won't exist any longer.

Comment: disconnect is reported at next try to read but timeout just acts the same but connection is still valid. So the only sign I have is, that after disconnect I get an error right away, but I can't use timing to distinguish the two scenarios. I found another implementation of serial for go that uses unix-like select before reads (go.bug.st/serial) and could add timeout to the implementation.So I now have a working solution. I will send a pull request to the implementer so others can use it too.